Grouping a table by its type on different columns
I have a table with two columns (type, id) that has the following structure:



id
type




A123
ACCOUNT


C123
CLIENT


O123
ORDER


A124
ACCOUNT


O124
ORDER


C125
CLIENT



I want to be able to do a SELECT on this table with alias columns of account_id_column, client_id_column and order_id_column where it groups it by type into three different columns like the following:



account_id_column
client_id_column
order_id_column




A123
C123
O123


A124
C125
O124



But not sure how to do this? Do I have to use a JOIN on the tables and then use a where clause on the type and then group by on it?

Presumably they're grouped by having the same number in the ID column? Does the ID have any particular format?

And what database are you using?

@Schwern They have distinct IDs. In the second table in the first column account_id_column the values A123, A124 are distinct ids. The relationship of ID A123, A124 is that they type is ACCOUNT. So that is why the first column is like that. The second table columns names are just aliases.

How do you know that A123 and C123 and O123 are to be grouped?

@Schwern The prefix of A means ACCOUNT type. Prefix of C is CLIENT type. Prefix of O is ORDER type. The columns of the second table are just aliases that are grouped by type. The second table is how I want my select to look like.

So you know A123, C123, and O123 are to be grouped because they all have 123 in common? And the format is always X###?

@Schwern Haha no, I want it grouped by type. The type determines how it should be grouped. You see how the second table first column of account_id_column has A123 and A124 as its rows? That is because those are all the ids that have type "ACCOUNT".

Oh, I see. You want one column to list all the accounts (in order?) and one to list all the clients, and one to list all the orders. Would you add C125 to the data and show how that fits in?

@Schwern Correct. Yes I will edit by table to include C125.

@Schwern I have updated to in C125 .

Thanks. And what database are you using?

@Schwern I am using PostGresSQL

SQL queries are row based, but you want columns. This requires a pivot. We need something in common for each row so we can group them together. We can add a row_number to each row to put them in order. Then we pivot them into individual columns by grouping by the row number.
with ordered_things as (
  select
    row_number() over(partition by type order by id asc) as rn,
    id, type
  from things
)
select
  coalesce(max(id) filter(where type = 'ACCOUNT'), '') as account_id,
  coalesce(max(id) filter(where type = 'CLIENT'), '') as client_id,
  coalesce(max(id) filter(where type = 'ORDER'), '') as order_id
from ordered_things
group by rn
order by rn

Since we know there's only one ID for each type in the group, max(id) is just a way to satisfy the need for each column of a group by query to be an aggregated function.
coalesce just gets rid of unsightly nulls when there isn't an equal number of ids for each type.
Demonstration.
